# YouTube application for Android

Tags: android, youtube

I want to develop a YouTube application for Android with the following functionalities:

1. Login
2. Comment on videos
3. Download on Android
4. Play videos by streaming and also by download

Please give me some useful way to solve this problem.

Comment: Refer [here][1] for solution. It provides a good understanding.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246212/android-youtube-upload-video-with-static-username-and-password

Comment: This is a bad question. way to generic.

Answer (score 1):

please refer to youtube api here : https://developers.google.com/youtube/

You can find options to login, comment on videos and view videos. For downloading videos,check:

1. http://www.ngcoders.com/php-script/php-youtube-video-downloader-script/
2. [http: //code.google.com/p/pytube/](http://code.google.com/p/pytube/)