# android youtube upload video with static username and password

Tags: android, youtube-api

i am uploading video to youtube which by default uploads to user who have login in google account.

But i want to set that all video should upload using my static gmailID and password

Is it possible to Login in google account directly using static emailid and password ?

Or any other good api or example to upload video in youtube.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have uploaded youtube video successfully.

- Record video and upload
- Videos from sdcard

by using [this](http://code.google.com/p/ytd-android/)

steps:

1) Download ytd-android-0.2.tar.gz  from this [link](http://code.google.com/p/ytd-android/downloads/list)

2) Import as an android project.

3) Replace file: **GlsAuthorizer.java** with **ClientLoginAuthorizer.java**

4) Set Username and password in **ClientLoginAuthorizer.java**

5) Register your email id with **www.appspot.com**

6) Set all values in **string.xml file**

7) Run project.....  here you go.

code for **ClientLoginAuthorizer.java**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;




/**
 * Created by IntelliJ IDEA. User: jarekw Date: Nov 18, 2010 Time: 11:21:36 PM
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
public class ClientLoginAuthorizer implements Authorizer {
    public static final String YOUTUBE_AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE = "youtube";
    private static final String AUTH_URL = "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin";
    private Context ctx;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = ClientLoginAuthorizer.class
            .getSimpleName();

    public ClientLoginAuthorizer(Context context) {
        this.ctx = context;

    }

    @Override
    public void fetchAccounts(AuthorizationListener<String[]> listener) {
        // not used

    }

    @Override
    public void addAccount(Activity activity,
            AuthorizationListener<String> listener) {
        // not used

    }

    @Override
    public void fetchAuthToken(String accountName, Activity activity,
            AuthorizationListener<String> listener) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Getting " + YOUTUBE_AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE + " authToken for "
                + accountName);
        try {
            String token = getCLAuthToken(accountName);
            listener.onSuccess(token);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            listener.onError(e);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthToken(String accountName) {
        try {
            String token = getCLAuthToken(accountName);
            return token;
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;

        }
    }

    public String getCLAuthToken(String accountName) throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = getGDataUrlConnection(AUTH_URL);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        String template = "Email=%s&Passwd=%s&service=%s&source=%s";
        String userName = "USERNAME"; // TODO
        String password = "PASSWORD"; // TODO
        String service = YOUTUBE_AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE;
        String source = ctx.getString(R.string.client_id);
        String loginData = String.format(template, encode(userName),
                encode(password), service, source);
        OutputStreamWriter outStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(
                urlConnection.getOutputStream());
        outStreamWriter.write(loginData);
        outStreamWriter.close();
        int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode != 200) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Got an error response : " + responseCode + " "
                    + urlConnection.getResponseMessage());
            throw new IOException(urlConnection.getResponseMessage());
        } else {

            InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.startsWith("Auth=")) {
                    String split[] = line.split("=");
                    String token = split[1];
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Auth Token : " + token);
                    return token;
                }
            }
        }

        throw new IOException("Could not read response");

    }

    private String encode(String string) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        return URLEncoder.encode(string, "UTF-8");

    }

    private HttpURLConnection getGDataUrlConnection(String urlString)
            throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        return connection;

    }

    @Override
    public String getFreshAuthToken(String accountName, String authToken) {
        return getAuthToken(accountName);

    }

    public static class ClientLoginAuthorizerFactory implements
            AuthorizerFactory {
        public Authorizer getAuthorizer(Context context, String authTokenType) {
            return new ClientLoginAuthorizer(context);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is extremely helpful. What I'm not clear on is what you need to do once you have the Auth token (which I'm getting now by calling getAuthToken() ).  How do you actually make the file upload call?

Comment: Good work but How can we get dev_id, client_id and domain name

Comment: ClientLogin is deprecated now!!

Comment: nice and thanks for code...now i am able to upload video on youtube

Comment: @VivekKumarSrivastava: Welcome :) have a nice developing.

Comment: @MAC how to upload private and public video using this can you pls help me

Comment: @MAC I tried this but it is giving me this error

W/System.err(14529): java.io.IOException: Forbidden
W/System.err(14529):  at com.example.youtubeshare.YoutubeUploader.getClientAuthToken(YoutubeUploader.java:107)

Comment: how i can get domain name ?

Comment: I got Exception like 404 File No Found Exception when i tried with static user name and password. how to resolve this @MAC?

Comment: This example not working now the AUTH_URL = "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin"; is depricated now

Comment: @VivekKumarSrivastava could you please tell me how to get dev_id, client_id and domain

Answer (score 13):

**I have wrapped uploading feature from project referred in [MAC'S answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10432215/703851) into single utility class :**

Here is `YoutubeUploader.java`

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore.Video;
import android.util.Log;

public class YoutubeUploader {

    private static final String TAG = "YoutubeUploader";

    // After creating project at http://www.appspot.com DEFAULT_YTD_DOMAIN == <Developers Console Project ID>.appspot.com [ You can find from Project -> Administration -> Application settings]
    public static final String DEFAULT_YTD_DOMAIN = "developerconsolid.appspot.com";

    // I used Google APIs Console Project Title as Domain name: 
    public static final String DEFAULT_YTD_DOMAIN_NAME = "Domain Name";

    //From Google Developer Console from same project (Created by SHA1; project package)
    //Example https://console.developers.google.com/project/apps~gtl-android-youtube-test/apiui/credential
    public static final String DEVELOPER_KEY = "developer key";

    // CLIENT_ID == Google APIs Console Project Number: 
    public static final String CLIENT_ID = "client_id";

    public static final String YOUTUBE_AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE = "youtube";

    private static final String AUTH_URL = "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin";

    // Uploader's user-name and password
    private static final String USER_NAME = "usersemail@useremail.usersemail";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "userspassword";

    private static final String INITIAL_UPLOAD_URL = "https://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/resumable/feeds/api/users/default/uploads";

    private static String getClientAuthToken() {

        try {

            URL url = new URL(AUTH_URL);

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            String template = "Email=%s&Passwd=%s&service=%s&source=%s";

            String userName = USER_NAME; // TODO
            String password = PASSWORD; // TODO

            String service = YOUTUBE_AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE; 
            String source = CLIENT_ID;

            userName = URLEncoder.encode(userName, "UTF-8");
            password = URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");

            String loginData = String.format(template, userName, password, service, source);

            OutputStreamWriter outStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            outStreamWriter.write(loginData);
            outStreamWriter.close();

            int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode != 200) {

                Log.d(TAG, "Got an error response : " + responseCode + " "  + urlConnection.getResponseMessage());

                throw new IOException(urlConnection.getResponseMessage());

            } else {

                InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String line = null;

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                    if (line.startsWith("Auth=")) {

                        String split[] = line.split("=");
                        String token = split[1];

                        Log.d(TAG, "Auth Token : " + token);
                        return token;
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static String upload(YoutubeUploadRequest uploadRequest, ProgressListner listner, Activity activity) {

        totalBytesUploaded = 0;

        String authToken = getClientAuthToken();

        if(authToken != null) {

            String uploadUrl = uploadMetaData(uploadRequest, authToken, activity, true);

            File file = getFileFromUri(uploadRequest.getUri(), activity);

            long currentFileSize = file.length();

            int uploadChunk = 1024 * 1024 * 3; // 3MB

            int start = 0;
            int end = -1;

            String videoId = null;

            double fileSize = currentFileSize;

            while (fileSize > 0) {

                if (fileSize - uploadChunk > 0) {
                    end = start + uploadChunk - 1;
                } else {
                    end = start + (int) fileSize - 1;
                }

                Log.d(TAG, String.format("start=%s end=%s total=%s", start, end, file.length()));

                try {

                    videoId = gdataUpload(file, uploadUrl, start, end, authToken, listner);
                    fileSize -= uploadChunk;
                    start = end + 1;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"Error during upload : " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }

            if (videoId != null) {
                return videoId;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static int totalBytesUploaded = 0;

    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    private static String gdataUpload(File file, String uploadUrl, int start, int end, String clientLoginToken, ProgressListner listner) throws IOException {

        int chunk = end - start + 1;
        int bufferSize = 4096;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(file);

        URL url = new URL(uploadUrl);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", String.format("GoogleLogin auth=\"%s\"",  clientLoginToken));
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("GData-Version", "2");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("X-GData-Client", CLIENT_ID);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("X-GData-Key", String.format("key=%s", DEVELOPER_KEY));
        // some mobile proxies do not support PUT, using X-HTTP-Method-Override to get around this problem

        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("X-HTTP-Method-Override", "PUT");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        urlConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(chunk);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "video/3gpp");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Range", String.format("bytes %d-%d/%d", start, end,
                file.length()));

        Log.d(TAG, urlConnection.getRequestProperty("Content-Range"));

        OutputStream outStreamWriter = urlConnection.getOutputStream();

        fileStream.skip(start);

        double currentFileSize = file.length();

        int bytesRead;
        int totalRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = fileStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) != -1) {
            outStreamWriter.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            totalRead += bytesRead;
            totalBytesUploaded += bytesRead;

            double percent = (totalBytesUploaded / currentFileSize) * 100;

            if(listner != null){
                listner.onUploadProgressUpdate((int) percent);
            }

            System.out.println("GTL You tube upload progress: " + percent + "%");
             /*
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, String.format(
                "fileSize=%f totalBytesUploaded=%f percent=%f", currentFileSize,
                totalBytesUploaded, percent));
             */

            //dialog.setProgress((int) percent);
            // TODO My settings

            if (totalRead == (end - start + 1)) {
                break;
            }
        }

        outStreamWriter.close();

        int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

        Log.d(TAG, "responseCode=" + responseCode);
        Log.d(TAG, "responseMessage=" + urlConnection.getResponseMessage());

        try {
            if (responseCode == 201) {
                String videoId = parseVideoId(urlConnection.getInputStream());

                return videoId;
            } else if (responseCode == 200) {
                Set<String> keySet = urlConnection.getHeaderFields().keySet();
                String keys = urlConnection.getHeaderFields().keySet().toString();
                Log.d(TAG, String.format("Headers keys %s.", keys));
                for (String key : keySet) {
                    Log.d(TAG, String.format("Header key %s value %s.", key, urlConnection.getHeaderField(key)));          
                }
                Log.w(TAG, "Received 200 response during resumable uploading");
                throw new IOException(String.format("Unexpected response code : responseCode=%d responseMessage=%s", responseCode,
                        urlConnection.getResponseMessage()));
            } else {
                if ((responseCode + "").startsWith("5")) {
                    String error = String.format("responseCode=%d responseMessage=%s", responseCode,
                            urlConnection.getResponseMessage());
                    Log.w(TAG, error);
                    // TODO - this exception will trigger retry mechanism to kick in
                    // TODO - even though it should not, consider introducing a new type so
                    // TODO - resume does not kick in upon 5xx
                    throw new IOException(error);
                } else if (responseCode == 308) {
                    // OK, the chunk completed succesfully 
                    Log.d(TAG, String.format("responseCode=%d responseMessage=%s", responseCode,
                            urlConnection.getResponseMessage()));
                } else {
                    // TODO - this case is not handled properly yet
                    Log.w(TAG, String.format("Unexpected return code : %d %s while uploading :%s", responseCode,
                            urlConnection.getResponseMessage(), uploadUrl));
                }
            }
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static String parseVideoId(InputStream atomDataStream) throws ParserConfigurationException,
    SAXException, IOException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(atomDataStream);

        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS("*", "*");
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = nodes.item(i);
            String nodeName = node.getNodeName();
            if (nodeName != null && nodeName.equals("yt:videoid")) {
                return node.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static File getFileFromUri(Uri uri, Activity activity) {

        try {
            String filePath = null;

            String[] proj = { Video.VideoColumns.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(uri, proj, null, null, null);

            if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Video.VideoColumns.DATA);
                filePath = cursor.getString(column_index);
            }

            cursor.close();

            //String filePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Video.VideoColumns.DATA));

            File file = new File(filePath);
            cursor.close();
            return file;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static String uploadMetaData(YoutubeUploadRequest uploadRequest, String clientLoginToken, Activity activity, boolean retry) {

        try {

            File file = getFileFromUri(uploadRequest.getUri(), activity);

            if(file != null) {

                String uploadUrl = INITIAL_UPLOAD_URL;
                URL url = new URL(uploadUrl);

                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", String.format("GoogleLogin auth=\"%s\"", clientLoginToken));
                connection.setRequestProperty("GData-Version", "2");
                connection.setRequestProperty("X-GData-Client", CLIENT_ID);
                connection.setRequestProperty("X-GData-Key", String.format("key=%s", DEVELOPER_KEY));

                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/atom+xml");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Slug", file.getAbsolutePath());

                String title = uploadRequest.getTitle();
                String description = uploadRequest.getDescription();
                String category = uploadRequest.getCategory();
                String tags = uploadRequest.getTags();

                String template = readFile(activity, R.raw.gdata).toString();
                String atomData = String.format(template, title, description, category, tags);

                /*String template = readFile(activity, R.raw.gdata_geo).toString();
                atomData = String.format(template, title, description, category, tags,
                    videoLocation.getLatitude(), videoLocation.getLongitude());*/

                OutputStreamWriter outStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
                outStreamWriter.write(atomData);
                outStreamWriter.close();

                int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

                if (responseCode < 200 || responseCode >= 300) {

                    // The response code is 40X

                    if ((responseCode + "").startsWith("4") && retry) {

                        Log.d(TAG, "retrying to fetch auth token for ");

                        clientLoginToken = getClientAuthToken();

                        // Try again with fresh token
                        return uploadMetaData(uploadRequest, clientLoginToken, activity, false);
                    } else {
                        return null;
                    }
                }

                return connection.getHeaderField("Location");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static CharSequence readFile(Activity activity, int id) {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(activity.getResources().openRawResource(id)));
            String line;
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line).append('\n');
            }
            // Chomp the last newline
            buffer.deleteCharAt(buffer.length() - 1);
            return buffer;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "";
        } finally {
            closeStream(in);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Closes the specified stream.
     *
     * @param stream The stream to close.
     */
    private static void closeStream(Closeable stream) {
        if (stream != null) {
            try {
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Ignore
            }
        }
    }  

    public static interface ProgressListner {

        void onUploadProgressUpdate(int progress);
    }
}
```

And here is `YoutubeUploadRequest.java`

```
import android.net.Uri;

public class YoutubeUploadRequest {

    private static final String DEFAULT_VIDEO_CATEGORY = "News";
    private static final String DEFAULT_VIDEO_TAGS = "mobile";

    private String title;
    private String strUri;
    private String description;
    private String category = DEFAULT_VIDEO_CATEGORY;
    private String tags = DEFAULT_VIDEO_TAGS;

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }
    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }
    public String getTags() {
        return tags;
    }
    public void setTags(String tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }
    public String getStrUri() {
        return strUri;
    }
    public void setStrUri(String strUri) {
        this.strUri = strUri;
    }
    public Uri getUri() {
        return Uri.parse(strUri);
    }
    public void setUri(Uri uri) {
        this.strUri = uri.toString();
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

Also you will need `raw/gdata.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007"> <media:group> <media:title type="plain">%s</media:title> <media:description type="plain">%s</media:description> <media:category scheme="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat">%s</media:category> <media:keywords>%s</media:keywords> </media:group> </entry>
```

Here is sample activity to use it : `MainActivity.java`

```
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.trialanderror.YoutubeUploader.ProgressListner;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private static final int CAPTURE_RETURN = 1;
    private static final int GALLERY_RETURN = 2;
    private static final int SUBMIT_RETURN = 3;

    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    private Button btnCaptureVideo;
    private Button btnSelectFromGallery;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnCaptureVideo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCaptureVideo);
        btnCaptureVideo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setAction("android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE");
                startActivityForResult(i, CAPTURE_RETURN);
            }
        });

        btnSelectFromGallery = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSelectFromGallery);
        btnSelectFromGallery.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intent.setType("video/*");

                List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent,  PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
                if (list.size() <= 0) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "no video picker intent on this hardware");
                    return;
                }

                startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_RETURN);
            }
        });

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnSelectFromGallery.setEnabled(true);
        btnCaptureVideo.setEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
        case CAPTURE_RETURN:
        case GALLERY_RETURN:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                /*Intent intent = new Intent(this, SubmitActivity.class);
                intent.setData(data.getData());
                startActivityForResult(intent, SUBMIT_RETURN);*/

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnSelectFromGallery.setEnabled(false);
                btnCaptureVideo.setEnabled(false);  

                uploadYoutube(data.getData());  
            }
            break;
        case SUBMIT_RETURN:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "thank you!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                // Toast.makeText(DetailsActivity.this, "submit failed or cancelled",
                // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    private void uploadYoutube(final Uri data) {

        new AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                YoutubeUploadRequest request = new YoutubeUploadRequest();
                request.setUri(data);
                //request.setCategory(category);
                //request.setTags(tags);
                request.setTitle("MPRJ Video Tite");
                request.setDescription("MPRJ Video Test");

                YoutubeUploader.upload(request, new ProgressListner() {

                    @Override
                    public void onUploadProgressUpdate(int progress) {

                        publishProgress(progress);
                    }
                }, MainActivity.this);
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
                progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);

                if(values[0] == 100){
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btnSelectFromGallery.setEnabled(true);
                    btnCaptureVideo.setEnabled(true);
                }
            };
        }.execute();
    }
}
```

Layout for sample activity `activity_main.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="@string/upload_video" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCaptureVideo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/capture_video" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSelectFromGallery"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/select_from_gallery" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Initial Upload URL change from http to https, I have edited in the answer. Thanks for the good work, works like a charm :)

Comment: Hi how can i upload public and private video using this code. Can you please help me

Comment: spend 2 days on it. yet not working. getClientAuthToken() always returning null because the condition 'if (line.startsWith("Auth="))' always false.

Comment: I tried this, but it gives me error.@Vaibhav A. Jani

04-22 17:05:05.180: W/System.err(14529): java.io.IOException: Forbidden

Comment: how i can get domain name?

Comment: getting response code 500 instead of 400 at this location 
`if (responseCode < 200 || responseCode >= 300) {
                         // The response code is 40X
                    if ((responseCode + "").startsWith("4") && retry) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "retrying to fetch auth token for ");
                             clientLoginToken = getClientAuthToken();........`

Comment: I got Exception like 404 File No Found Exception when i tried with static user name and password. how to resolve this @Vaibhav

Comment: https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin url not supported now please check https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/client-login