# Upload a video in specific youtube account - Android

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api

I want to create an app that the user can upload a video stored on the device or recorded with the camera, and automatically upload it in a specific account that **I own**. The problem is that I'm trying with the ytdirect tutorials over the net, but the [getting started tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/youtube-direct/wiki/GettingStarted) is not that simple to interpret and is really complicated for something that (i think) has to be simpler maybe using the API.

I have followed this steps on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246212/android-youtube-upload-video-with-static-username-and-password/10432215#10432215), that seems to be a better or at least simpler way to achieve what I'm looking for using the same YouTube Direct, but the replacement of the GlsAuthorizer.java with ClientLoginAuthorizer.java in that answer is throwing me some errors in the project (specifically in the SubmitActivity.java on the onCreate with the GlsAuthorizer.GlsAuthorizerFactory()) (1).

I have the Developer Key and the App ID, and the URL associated to it (xyz.appspot.com). I don't know what is the default_ytd_domain_name located in the strings.xml from the [project](http://code.google.com/p/ytd-android/downloads/detail?name=ytd-android-0.2.tar.gz&can=2&q=) (2).

There is any other way to upload a video in YouTube (with a tutorial or a sample code that I could use) or someone has a more detailed sequence of steps to follow to achieve the upload using the second link above, because I'm only missing two (2) of the points on the steps of that answer.

Answer (score 0):

I do something like this to get a new access token if it has expired. Then I pass it back to the client and do the upload with this token.

```
getYoutubeToken: function() {

        var now = moment();
        var result;
        if (now.diff(Meteor.settings.youtube.expiration, 'minutes') >= 50) {
            console.log('Getting new access token...')

            var options = {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                },
                content: "client_secret=" + Meteor.settings.youtube.client_secret + "&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=" + Meteor.settings.youtube.refresh_token + "&client_id=" + Meteor.settings.youtube.client_id
            }

            try {
                result = HTTP.call("POST", 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token', options);
                Meteor.settings.youtube.access_token = result.data.access_token;
                Meteor.settings.youtube.expiration = moment();

                return Meteor.settings.youtube.access_token;
            } catch (e) {
                // Got a network error, time-out or HTTP error in the 400 or 500 range.
                return false;
            }


        } else {
            console.log('Returning access token...')
            return Meteor.settings.youtube.access_token;
        }

    }
```