# How to solve Android App Youtube Direct upload 403 error?

Tags: java, android, windows, upload, youtube

I've tried to make an Android App which uploads recorded or selected videos from the sd card.
I managed to do this with the Browser Method (App directs to youtube) with the Youtube API, but I wanted to have a direct upload to Youtube while staying in the App itself.

Then I found out about the App "YouTube Direct" http://code.google.com/p/ytd-android/ which kind off works like I want in my own App.
The Problem is, that the Demo App of YouTube doesn't work on my Device.

When I try to submit a Video I get the Error Message:
response code='Forbidden'(code 403)
http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/resumable/feeds/api/users/default/uploads

Anyone an idea how to fix that?

By the way:
I've found here this "tutorial":
[android youtube upload video with static username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246212/android-youtube-upload-video-with-static-username-and-password/10432215#10432215)

But this doesn't work, cause when I replace GlsAuthorizer.java with ClientLoginAuthorizer.java, there occure errors in other classes of this Youtube Direct App.

Comment: Youtube has a [Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video) which has upload capabilities, you might want to investigate using it instead of that third party library.

Comment: I'am programming my App with Java, in the link you provided Python is mentioned. Is there a solution with Java? + I thought Youtube Direct was a official Application by YouTube/Google, I guess I was wrong there.

Comment: It's a web service API, you can access it from any language (that supports making HTTP calls).

Comment: Ok thank you. I'll study it

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a OAuth 2.0 client IDs and API key for your project on the https://console.developers.google.com/

For more :  https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#setting-up-oauth-20