# how to upload video on youtube from application in android?

Tags: android, youtube

I am trying to upload video to youtube from my app. I found many references to do this but all those first open youtube app on device then uploads video form that app and I want to upload directly without opening youtube app, can anybody tell me how can I do this, Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10432215/1289716)