# Youtube URL malformed URL exception

Tags: java, android, youtube, youtube-api

I am using the following function to get a URL to upload a video to Youtube from my Android Device:

Class level Variable:

```
private static final String INITIAL_UPLOAD_URL = "http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/resumable/feeds/api/users/default/uploads";
```

Function:

```
private static String uploadMetaData(YoutubeUploadRequest uploadRequest, String clientLoginToken, Activity activity, boolean retry) {
        System.out.println("Upload Request \n"+uploadRequest+"\n Client login token"+clientLoginToken+"\nActivity: "+"\nActivity name: "+activity+"\nRetry value:"+retry); 
        try {

            File file = getFileFromUri(uploadRequest.getUri(), activity);

            if(file != null) {

                String uploadUrl = INITIAL_UPLOAD_URL;
                System.out.println(uploadUrl); 
                URL url = new URL(uploadUrl);

                System.out.println(url);

                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", String.format("GoogleLogin auth=\"%s\"", clientLoginToken));
                connection.setRequestProperty("GData-Version", "2");
                connection.setRequestProperty("X-GData-Client", CLIENT_ID);
                connection.setRequestProperty("X-GData-Key", String.format("key=%s", DEVELOPER_KEY));

                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/atom+xml");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Slug", file.getAbsolutePath());

                String title = uploadRequest.getTitle();
                String description = uploadRequest.getDescription();
                String category = uploadRequest.getCategory();
                String tags = uploadRequest.getTags();

                String template = readFile(activity, R.raw.gdata).toString();
                String atomData = String.format(template, title, description, category, tags);

                /*String template = readFile(activity, R.raw.gdata_geo).toString();
                atomData = String.format(template, title, description, category, tags,
                    videoLocation.getLatitude(), videoLocation.getLongitude());*/

                OutputStreamWriter outStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
                outStreamWriter.write(atomData);
                outStreamWriter.close();

                int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

                if (responseCode < 200 || responseCode >= 300) {

                    // The response code is 40X

                    if ((responseCode + "").startsWith("4") && retry) {

                        Log.d(TAG, "retrying to fetch auth token for ");

                        clientLoginToken = getClientAuthToken();

                        // Try again with fresh token
                        return uploadMetaData(uploadRequest, clientLoginToken, activity, false);
                    } else {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(connection.getHeaderField("Location"));
                return connection.getHeaderField("Location");

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Message"+e); 
        }

        return null;
    }
```

I am sure of the parameters I pass to the function, they are all correct. I have cross checked by debugging, I call this function like:

```
String uploadUrl = uploadMetaData(uploadRequest, authToken, activity, true);
```

But I get an error, Malformed URL exception, any idea where I might be going wrong?

These are the parameters I pass:

```
04-11 09:59:54.015: I/System.out(19815): com.xx.xxvideo.YoutubeUploadRequest@4257f060
04-11 09:59:54.016: I/System.out(19815):  Client login tokenDQAAAHABAAAXXoe8KR8BuYY_0KE2cxW_lMzsUn7T81NbFsrF39OcQLmC-lpAjFCBv1EhBvzJFKp51e4Y8ad13YbRms6SifTDDhWyObvs7cDctKyMTHbgwFXKuZ6in-vBloUfYMLugjbF2fXfSqYehddquxNgaARVQFwd0Ks986MBJ0CceB1vcLSq31BNjWuG-mVHfhQbAj2xJoBHDaD-RAWDYJk4l0XzwFIIh3uP19TjeIocRQeeahchAi9hsl5UdPhG1WRXLpsCvXm-6vDt5NXzF3RrdUIKZlBNif_j0sSPO2jH1sSz6UfeEtSYblISdSx-XyJIRHF6f4dx7BlBa-QZ-30eY-mzTMNpYV2FSPP1WhIBVnGvGsAnOrJG-7vakx1upxGLgyFotD82Th23afQ38ax87GqX7gT-Vqk5elJ250WMHOHSYgoPGpe--B5PmBk3JPyT8wMtYycmAplJuuDFUDXuESnxPIlTpDpE3XFpljszQBQUPg
04-11 09:59:54.016: I/System.out(19815): Activity: 
04-11 09:59:54.016: I/System.out(19815): Activity name: com.xx.xxvideo.MainActivity@42552cf0
04-11 09:59:54.017: I/System.out(19815): Retry value:true
```

Comment: What's your INITIAL_UPLOAD_URL?

Comment: Can you try the upload using "https" instead of "http" and update the status?

Comment: Sure, also here is the complete implementation I had taken reference from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246212/android-youtube-upload-video-with-static-username-and-password

Comment: Man it workds!! WooHooo!! You are my savior for this day :)