# Upload video to Youtube via android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I'm a new programmer in Android studio.

I am trying to create a button that gets a file location and uploads it to my youtube account:

I succeeded to get a video file's directory in my android code:

```
File mediaFile = 
    new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()....)
```

I added a button that calls `UploadToYoutube` function.

Now I would like to upload it to my youtube account through the file path I have.

Can someone direct me?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I think it was answered before please check this [answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246212/android-youtube-upload-video-with-static-username-and-password/10432215#10432215

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My suggestion:

**Get Start**

Obtaining authorization credentials

- https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application?hl=en

Implementing OAuth 2.0 Authentication

- https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication?hl=en

YouTube API: Client Libraries

- https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/libraries?hl=en

Using google-api-java-client:

- https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client

  **Next step:**

Use YouTube Data API (v3)

### **[Sources Examples in](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java?hl=en)**

[Post a channel bulletin](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java?hl=en#post_a_channel_bulletin)

[Create and manage YouTube video caption tracks](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java?hl=en#create_and_manage_youtube_video_caption_tracks)

[Add a featured video](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java?hl=en#add_a_featured_video)

[Retrieve my uploads](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java?hl=en#retrieve_my_uploads)

[Create a playlist](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java?hl=en#create_a_playlist)

[Search by keyword](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java?hl=en#search_by_keyword)

[Search by topic](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java?hl=en#search_by_topic)

[Search by geolocation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java?hl=en#search_by_geolocation)

[Add a channel subscription](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java?hl=en#add_a_channel_subscription)

[Upload a video thumbnail image](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java?hl=en#upload_a_video_thumbnail_image)

**[Upload a video](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java?hl=en#upload_a_video)**  << Example code in java : )

[Update a video](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java?hl=en#update_a_video)

Comment: For the detailed answer and references, +1

Comment: @Owehbeh can you give me full code to upload video to static username and password using oauth2, from my android application?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working code

```
        ContentValues content = new ContentValues(4);
        content.put(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATE_ADDED,
                System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
        content.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
        content.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, path);
        ContentResolver resolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
        Uri uri1 =  Uri.fromFile(new File(path)); 

        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("video/*");
        sharingIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.youtube");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Title");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Desc");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri1);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share to"));
```