# How to create default_ytd_domain name while uploading video to youtube in android

Tags: android

I am Uploading video to youtube via my application using this example [android youtube upload video with static username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246212/android-youtube-upload-video-with-static-username-and-password) but when i try to upload video its gives me error that i dont have right domain name ..how to create domain name i have done everything please suggests what i need to do?

```
public class YoutubeUploader {

private static final String TAG = "YoutubeUploader";

// After creating project at http://www.appspot.com DEFAULT_YTD_DOMAIN == <Developers Console Project ID>.appspot.com [ You can find from Project -> Administration -> Application settings]
public static final String DEFAULT_YTD_DOMAIN = "developerconsolid.appspot.com";

// I used Google APIs Console Project Title as Domain name: 
public static final String DEFAULT_YTD_DOMAIN_NAME = "Domain Name";

//From Google Developer Console from same project (Created by SHA1; project package)
//Example https://console.developers.google.com/project/apps~gtl-android-youtube-test/apiui/credential
public static final String DEVELOPER_KEY = "developer key";

// CLIENT_ID == Google APIs Console Project Number: 
public static final String CLIENT_ID = "client_id";

public static final String YOUTUBE_AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE = "youtube";

private static final String AUTH_URL = "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin";

// Uploader's user-name and password
private static final String USER_NAME = "usersemail@useremail.usersemail";
private static final String PASSWORD = "userspassword";

private static final String INITIAL_UPLOAD_URL = "https://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/resumable/feeds/api/users/default/uploads";

private static String getClientAuthToken() {

    try {

        URL url = new URL(AUTH_URL);

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        String template = "Email=%s&Passwd=%s&service=%s&source=%s";

        String userName = USER_NAME; // TODO
        String password = PASSWORD; // TODO

        String service = YOUTUBE_AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE; 
        String source = CLIENT_ID;

        userName = URLEncoder.encode(userName, "UTF-8");
        password = URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");

        String loginData = String.format(template, userName, password, service, source);

        OutputStreamWriter outStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
        outStreamWriter.write(loginData);
        outStreamWriter.close();

        int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode != 200) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Got an error response : " + responseCode + " "  + urlConnection.getResponseMessage());

            throw new IOException(urlConnection.getResponseMessage());

        } else {

            InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line = null;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                if (line.startsWith("Auth=")) {

                    String split[] = line.split("=");
                    String token = split[1];

                    Log.d(TAG, "Auth Token : " + token);
                    return token;
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

public static String upload(YoutubeUploadRequest uploadRequest, ProgressListner listner, Activity activity) {

    totalBytesUploaded = 0;

    String authToken = getClientAuthToken();

    if(authToken != null) {

        String uploadUrl = uploadMetaData(uploadRequest, authToken, activity, true);

        File file = getFileFromUri(uploadRequest.getUri(), activity);

        long currentFileSize = file.length();

        int uploadChunk = 1024 * 1024 * 3; // 3MB

        int start = 0;
        int end = -1;

        String videoId = null;

        double fileSize = currentFileSize;

        while (fileSize > 0) {

            if (fileSize - uploadChunk > 0) {
                end = start + uploadChunk - 1;
            } else {
                end = start + (int) fileSize - 1;
            }

            Log.d(TAG, String.format("start=%s end=%s total=%s", start, end, file.length()));

            try {

                videoId = gdataUpload(file, uploadUrl, start, end, authToken, listner);
                fileSize -= uploadChunk;
                start = end + 1;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Error during upload : " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        if (videoId != null) {
            return videoId;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

public static int totalBytesUploaded = 0;

@SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
private static String gdataUpload(File file, String uploadUrl, int start, int end, String clientLoginToken, ProgressListner listner) throws IOException {

    int chunk = end - start + 1;
    int bufferSize = 4096;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(file);

    URL url = new URL(uploadUrl);
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", String.format("GoogleLogin auth=\"%s\"",  clientLoginToken));
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("GData-Version", "2");
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("X-GData-Client", CLIENT_ID);
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("X-GData-Key", String.format("key=%s", DEVELOPER_KEY));
    // some mobile proxies do not support PUT, using X-HTTP-Method-Override to get around this problem

    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("X-HTTP-Method-Override", "PUT");
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

    urlConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(chunk);
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "video/3gpp");
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Range", String.format("bytes %d-%d/%d", start, end,
            file.length()));

    Log.d(TAG, urlConnection.getRequestProperty("Content-Range"));

    OutputStream outStreamWriter = urlConnection.getOutputStream();

    fileStream.skip(start);

    double currentFileSize = file.length();

    int bytesRead;
    int totalRead = 0;
    while ((bytesRead = fileStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) != -1) {
        outStreamWriter.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        totalRead += bytesRead;
        totalBytesUploaded += bytesRead;

        double percent = (totalBytesUploaded / currentFileSize) * 100;

        if(listner != null){
            listner.onUploadProgressUpdate((int) percent);
        }

        System.out.println("GTL You tube upload progress: " + percent + "%");
         /*
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, String.format(
            "fileSize=%f totalBytesUploaded=%f percent=%f", currentFileSize,
            totalBytesUploaded, percent));
         */

        //dialog.setProgress((int) percent);
        // TODO My settings

        if (totalRead == (end - start + 1)) {
            break;
        }
    }

    outStreamWriter.close();

    int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

    Log.d(TAG, "responseCode=" + responseCode);
    Log.d(TAG, "responseMessage=" + urlConnection.getResponseMessage());

    try {
        if (responseCode == 201) {
            String videoId = parseVideoId(urlConnection.getInputStream());

            return videoId;
        } else if (responseCode == 200) {
            Set<String> keySet = urlConnection.getHeaderFields().keySet();
            String keys = urlConnection.getHeaderFields().keySet().toString();
            Log.d(TAG, String.format("Headers keys %s.", keys));
            for (String key : keySet) {
                Log.d(TAG, String.format("Header key %s value %s.", key, urlConnection.getHeaderField(key)));          
            }
            Log.w(TAG, "Received 200 response during resumable uploading");
            throw new IOException(String.format("Unexpected response code : responseCode=%d responseMessage=%s", responseCode,
                    urlConnection.getResponseMessage()));
        } else {
            if ((responseCode + "").startsWith("5")) {
                String error = String.format("responseCode=%d responseMessage=%s", responseCode,
                        urlConnection.getResponseMessage());
                Log.w(TAG, error);
                // TODO - this exception will trigger retry mechanism to kick in
                // TODO - even though it should not, consider introducing a new type so
                // TODO - resume does not kick in upon 5xx
                throw new IOException(error);
            } else if (responseCode == 308) {
                // OK, the chunk completed succesfully 
                Log.d(TAG, String.format("responseCode=%d responseMessage=%s", responseCode,
                        urlConnection.getResponseMessage()));
            } else {
                // TODO - this case is not handled properly yet
                Log.w(TAG, String.format("Unexpected return code : %d %s while uploading :%s", responseCode,
                        urlConnection.getResponseMessage(), uploadUrl));
            }
        }
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

private static String parseVideoId(InputStream atomDataStream) throws ParserConfigurationException,
SAXException, IOException {
    DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = docBuilder.parse(atomDataStream);

    NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS("*", "*");
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        Node node = nodes.item(i);
        String nodeName = node.getNodeName();
        if (nodeName != null && nodeName.equals("yt:videoid")) {
            return node.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private static File getFileFromUri(Uri uri, Activity activity) {

    try {
        String filePath = null;

        String[] proj = { Video.VideoColumns.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(uri, proj, null, null, null);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Video.VideoColumns.DATA);
            filePath = cursor.getString(column_index);
        }

        cursor.close();

        //String filePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Video.VideoColumns.DATA));

        File file = new File(filePath);
        cursor.close();
        return file;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

private static String uploadMetaData(YoutubeUploadRequest uploadRequest, String clientLoginToken, Activity activity, boolean retry) {

    try {

        File file = getFileFromUri(uploadRequest.getUri(), activity);

        if(file != null) {

            String uploadUrl = INITIAL_UPLOAD_URL;
            URL url = new URL(uploadUrl);

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", String.format("GoogleLogin auth=\"%s\"", clientLoginToken));
            connection.setRequestProperty("GData-Version", "2");
            connection.setRequestProperty("X-GData-Client", CLIENT_ID);
            connection.setRequestProperty("X-GData-Key", String.format("key=%s", DEVELOPER_KEY));

            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/atom+xml");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Slug", file.getAbsolutePath());

            String title = uploadRequest.getTitle();
            String description = uploadRequest.getDescription();
            String category = uploadRequest.getCategory();
            String tags = uploadRequest.getTags();

            String template = readFile(activity, R.raw.gdata).toString();
            String atomData = String.format(template, title, description, category, tags);

            /*String template = readFile(activity, R.raw.gdata_geo).toString();
            atomData = String.format(template, title, description, category, tags,
                videoLocation.getLatitude(), videoLocation.getLongitude());*/

            OutputStreamWriter outStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            outStreamWriter.write(atomData);
            outStreamWriter.close();

            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode < 200 || responseCode >= 300) {

                // The response code is 40X

                if ((responseCode + "").startsWith("4") && retry) {

                    Log.d(TAG, "retrying to fetch auth token for ");

                    clientLoginToken = getClientAuthToken();

                    // Try again with fresh token
                    return uploadMetaData(uploadRequest, clientLoginToken, activity, false);
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }

            return connection.getHeaderField("Location");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

public static CharSequence readFile(Activity activity, int id) {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(activity.getResources().openRawResource(id)));
        String line;
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line).append('\n');
        }
        // Chomp the last newline
        buffer.deleteCharAt(buffer.length() - 1);
        return buffer;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return "";
    } finally {
        closeStream(in);
    }
}

/**
 * Closes the specified stream.
 *
 * @param stream The stream to close.
 */
private static void closeStream(Closeable stream) {
    if (stream != null) {
        try {
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Ignore
        }
    }
}  

public static interface ProgressListner {

    void onUploadProgressUpdate(int progress);
}
 }
```