# How to upload video from android app using youtube API V3?

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api

I have a requirement of uploading a video to YouTube from an android app. i want create an app, which I can upload videos to YouTube, but the problem is that devices that don't have google play service available. So I want to upload video using YouTube API.

1- I have gone through and call this API https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps 
but unable to get oAuth from here.

2- How to Upload video from youtube without google play service is it possible?

I have also tried 
[android youtube upload video with static username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246212/android-youtube-upload-video-with-static-username-and-password/10432215#10432215)
but google have deprecated this API. How I can implement in my android device using YouTube API v3.
Any help is appreciable.thanks.

Comment: Who is downvoter? Could you able to solve it? OR downvote without any reason?

Comment: May I use javascript library for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Try using [Google API Client API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/android)

The Google API Client Library for Java supports Android 1.5+